# Kendo MVC grid in edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo mvc grid set for inline editing. I have a dropdown that I would like to populate when the user selects edit, and the list needs to be populated based upon a value in the row (which is in a hidden field) 
     c.Bound(a => a.MyId)
                    .Hidden(true);

I have the dropdown that I wish to populate in an editor template (which I need as this dropdown is shared by several grids).

```
@model int?

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m)
            .AutoBind(true)
            .Filter("contains")
            .Placeholder("Select...")
            .DataTextField("MyOtherName")
            .DataValueField("MyOtherId")
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("Data_Read", "MyController").Data("OnAdditionalData");
                });
            })
            .Suggest(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
)
```

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)

With an additional data method in a script file ...

```
function OnAdditionalData()
{
    var myId = $("#MyId").val();

    return {  myId : myId };
}
```

I would like for the dropdown to populate when the user clicks on the row edit button. With the autobind property set to true, it does just that. But the value in the additional datat function is always an empty string. This value does not populate correctly until after the additional data method (verified using the JS console.) If I set autobind to false, the user has to click on the drop down in the editable row, but then the value of myId is correct.
I see what is going on, with autobind true the values from the row object is not being populated until after the read method of the ComboBox is called.

Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Comment: Take a look at the kendo-grid's `Event` property. You can set a function to run when the grid goes into Edit mode such as this: `.Events(e =>{e.Edit("onEdit");})`. Then in your javascript add: `function onEdit(e) {//Logic to be executed on Edit event}`. Check out this [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/forums/wiring-up-javascript-to-the-edit-and-delete-grid-commands) from Telerik.

Comment: I guess that may be my only option, firing the read event of the combox manually on row edit. Thanks